# Find only exact string

Tags: string, perl, indexing

I'm trying to find a string inside a string with Perl. For example:

```
str = "Hi sir, No data was received"
strtofind = "No data was received"
```

I'm using:

```
if(index($str,$strtofind) != -1)
```

But if the script receive another input like: `"Hi sir, No data sent"` it matches too (`No data`).

How to set TRUE if only it match all the `strtofind`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Could you supply an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Any chance you are confusing the logic of `!=`? The expression you are using is true, if the string is found. It would help if showed us a *complete* program, stripped down to a few lines and still exhibiting the problem.

Comment: Hi and thanks, the logic is:
`str = "Hi sir, No data was received"
strtofind = "No data was received"

#It match
if (index($str, $strtofind) != -1){
 $flagger = 1;
}

if($flagger == 0){
...code here...
}

str = "Hi sir, No data was sent"
strtofind = "No data was received"
#It match too
if (index($str, $strtofind) != -1){
 $flagger = 1;
}`

Comment: @proquibas That's not even valid code. There's something you're not showing us. Once again, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice.

Comment: https://eval.in/370359 so you need to set your $flagger like `$flagger = (index($str, $strtofind) != -1)`, or set it to zero prior to condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `\Q` and `\E` operators:

```
my $str = "Hi sir, No data was received";
my $strtofind = "No data was received";
if ($str =~ /\Q$strtofind\E/)
{
    print "Match\n";
}
```

Comment: Or [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

Comment: Thanks all for your help, all are correct, I was doing wrong comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The code you gave behaves in this way

```
  DB<4> $str="Hi sir, No data was received"

  DB<5> $strtofind="No data was received"

  DB<6> $str2="Hi sir, no data sent"

  DB<7> print index($str,$strtofind)
8
  DB<8> print index($str2,$strtofind)
-1
```

Which is *correct* according to your requirements.  If you are having a problem, it's not with the matching, it's elsewhere